# Error 500 Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() when trying to get to customize in WP

Tags: wordpress, customization

My site uninstalled all plugins so I reactivated and since then I have been greeted by Error 500 everytime I try to get to Customise (WP).

I checked out error_log and it's pointing to the funtions.php line 659 (starts 3rd line down):

```
function thrive_exclude_category($query)
{
    $hide_cat_option = thrive_get_theme_options('hide_cats_from_blog');

    if (!is_string($hide_cat_option)) {
        $hide_cat_option = "";
    }

    $hide_categories = is_array(json_decode($hide_cat_option)) ? json_decode($hide_cat_option) : array();
    $temp_query_string_part = "";
    foreach ($hide_categories as $temp_cat_id) {
        $temp_query_string_part .= "-" . $temp_cat_id . " ";
    }
```

This is probably simple stuff, however, I suck. I have been lumbered with maintaining the sites and really have no say in the matter. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did the error_log says? We need more details. Is it "Undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() ... "?

Comment: [05-Dec-2017 10:46:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() in /home/fgcpanel/public_html/futures-for-children.org/wp-content/themes/rise/functions.php on line 659
[05-Dec-2017 10:46:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() in /home/fgcpanel/public_html/futures-for-children.org/wp-content/themes/rise/functions.php on line 659

Comment: Try reactivate all plugins required by Thrive theme.

Comment: Thank you, can you upvote my answer and make it accepted? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the projects I found this problem too. After study logs and debug project I find this function don't know about another function which used in theme `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options()`. The main problem here in filter which running before all files will be included in theme. So function `thrive_exclude_category` don't find where declared `thrive_get_theme_options` because `pre_get_posts` running before we included files:

> add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'thrive_exclude_category')

We need run this filter after use `after_setup_theme`

```
function run_func(){
   add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'thrive_exclude_category', 999);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'run_func`);
```

After this you not get any error and you can use your filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try reactivate all plugins required by Thrive theme because of Fatal: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options()